# ast literal eval on string of numbers separated by spaces

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

There are different behavior of ast with different versions:

python2, python3.7:

```
ast.literal_eval("3 -1")
>> ValueError: malformed node or string
```

python3.4

```
ast.literal_eval("3 -1")
>> 2
```

Is there any documentation about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This documented in [bug 31778](https://bugs.python.org/issue31778).  The rationale for the stricter behaviour is that the old behaviour could lead to some values being incorrectly evaluated: for example the date string `2019-12-18` could be evaluated as an arithmetic expression instead of being left as a string.

Not evaluating expressions is more in keeping with the [documented behaviour](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

> The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.

per the bug report.